# Symfony translations in Twig templates with variables

Tags: php, symfony

- I have boostrapped a new Symfony 5.3 application with the cli.
- Followed https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#configuration
- I have a created a simple Twig template in a controller:

```
{% trans with {'%name%': 'Hans'} %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}

{{ 'Hello filter %name%'|trans({'%name%': 'Hans'}) }}
```

This yields:

```
Hello Hans 

Hello filter Hans
```

When I do

```
php bin/console translation:update --force en
```

The translation files are created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
  <file source-language="en" target-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <header>
      <tool tool-id="symfony" tool-name="Symfony"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="SzX5ua9" resname="Hello %name%">
        <source>Hello %name%</source>
        <target>__Hello %name%</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="6l2Ebbm" resname="Hello filter %name%">
        <source>Hello filter %name%</source>
        <target>__Hello filter %name%</target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

When I do a refresh of the site - the variables are not replaced anymore:

```
__Hello %name% 

__Hello filter %name%
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I dump the translations - and keep the variable replacement? Do I need to amend the translation files to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

When using the icu translation format - one has to amend the placeholders:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#message-placeholders

```
<target>__Hello filter {name}</target>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been a lot of time trying to find the reason to this problem. I don't understand why they don't put this in the main documentation page.